# Windows, HID USB Device, cannot write to the port

Tags: go, usb, hid

I'm working with HID USB Device and I need to write it some commands. There are tool called  SimpleHIDWrite which do it with success. But when I'm doing it from my application I receive either "Invalid function" or "The parameter is incorrect". I have made a lot of attempts with different libraries - the same result. From documentation I know that reportID should be 0x08 and command 0x02(or 0x00).
Below is my last test app on golang:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/karalabe/usb"
)

func main() {
    // Enumerate all the HID devices in alphabetical path order
    hids, err := usb.EnumerateHid(0, 0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(hids); i++ {
        for j := i + 1; j < len(hids); j++ {
            if hids[i].Path > hids[j].Path {
                hids[i], hids[j] = hids[j], hids[i]
            }
        }
    }

    var hidWanted usb.DeviceInfo

    for i, hid := range hids {
        fmt.Println(strings.Repeat("-", 128))
        fmt.Printf("HID #%d\n", i)
        fmt.Printf("  OS Path:      %s\n", hid.Path)
        fmt.Printf("  Vendor ID:    %#04x\n", hid.VendorID)
        fmt.Printf("  Product ID:   %#04x\n", hid.ProductID)
        fmt.Printf("  Release:      %d\n", hid.Release)
        fmt.Printf("  Serial:       %s\n", hid.Serial)
        fmt.Printf("  Manufacturer: %s\n", hid.Manufacturer)
        fmt.Printf("  Product:      %s\n", hid.Product)
        fmt.Printf("  Usage Page:   %d\n", hid.UsagePage)
        fmt.Printf("  Usage:        %d\n", hid.Usage)
        fmt.Printf("  Interface:    %d\n", hid.Interface)

        if hid.VendorID == 0x22b6 && hid.ProductID == 0x0100 {
            hidWanted = hid
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(strings.Repeat("=", 128))

    dev, err := hidWanted.Open()
    if err == nil {
        b := make([]byte, 37)
        b[0] = 0x08 // report id
        b[1] = 0x02 // cmd
        ln, err := dev.Write(b)
        fmt.Println("Write result", ln, err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Cannot write to the device: ", hidWanted)
    }
}
```

I don't any idea how to fix it please help.
Also I link picture with utilite where you can see HID description - may be it helps...
[image]